# Add Click Event to Dynamic Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How am I able to add a click event to this dynamic element and how to get the text of the clicked one?

```
$data.append("<tfoot><tr><td></td</tr></tfoot");

$("#tab2").html($data);
alert(data.n);

for (i = 0; i < data.n + 1; i++) {

    thelink = $('<a>', {
        text: i,
        href: '#'
    }).appendTo('tfoot');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `theLink` variable you create within the `for` loop is a jQuery object (the result of the call to `.appendTo()` is still the created link).

You can, as usual, call `.click(<function>)` on it to bind a function to the click event.

Example:

```
$data.append("<tfoot><tr><td></td</tr></tfoot>"); // added > at the end of the string
$("#tab2").html($data);
alert(data.n)

for (var i = 0; i < data.n + 1; i++) {            // added var before i
    var thelink = $('<a>', {                      // added var before thelink
        text: i,
        href: '#'
    }).appendTo('tfoot');

    // Now you can add the click event:
    thelink.click(function () {
        alert("Hello, you clicked the link number "+i);
    });
}
```

On a side note, maybe you should call `.appendTo('#tab2 tfoot')` instead of just `.appendTo('tfoot')` - the latter will add the link to all `tfoot`s on the page, the former just to `#tab2`'s `tfoot`.